# Is it a security risk to expose some authorization roles to the user over an API

Tags: api, authorization

I have an API (in this case GraphQL) and an accompanying app. My server is already censoring any data that the user is not authorized to see, so forget the risk of leaking any data.

There are certain actions I would like my client to take based on the user's role (logged-in, subscriber etc). A simple way to achieve this would be to return a list of roles to my client, so that the UI can respond accordingly. This logic is purely for optimising the UX, so if it went wrong the risk isn't in any way severe.

An alternative to this might be something like JWT, but we'd rather not implement this at this stage.

Is returning these roles inherently a security flaw? Or should I not worry about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing bad in the client or the UI knowing the allowed roles if it can help to provide a cleaner user experience. Said differently if a user is not allowed to go into the *Admin* page, it should not see a link leading there.

Simply server security should never rely on the client. That means that even if the client is never presented the link to the *Admin* page, the application should be prepared to get an unauthorized (because forged) request for it and reject it.

The underlying implementation does not really matter, provided the above rules are followed. That mean that a heavy client (anything more than a pure browser where javascript only smoothes interaction) should know the roles given to the user, and that the server should not rely on the requests coming from the expected client interfaces.